# Repository not found error on WSL2 when using git credential manager with windows credential manager (multiple git account)

Tags: git, github

I have 2 different github accounts and have saved both credentials in windows credential manager. I can switch the user by setting the namesapace, username and useremail per project. It works on winodws (vscode).

But it does not work in WSL2 for both accounts. I have used following command to set up GCM in WSL2

```bash
git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-credential-manager.exe"
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-git#git-credential-manager-setup

So, git work with default credential (the middle one from below screenshot) from windows credential manager on wsl2, but it doesn't work with the first one (the one with the namespace). When I try to run command `git push -u origin main` after creating a new repo, I get following error

```bash
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/san****/che****.git/' not found
```

[image: WCM]

Below are the commands I use to set my other account (the one with namespace).

```bash
git config credential.namespace git.san****
git config user.name "san****"
git config user.email "o****@gmail.com"
```

Git version on wsl2

```bash
git version 2.34.1
```

Git version on windows

```bash
git version 2.41.0.windows.1
```